# html button not calling its onclick js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this simple alert not work?

HTML:

`<button id="mybutton" type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>`

JS:

```
function add(){
alert("hello???");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k86mg0aj/

Comment: You've got the script set to OnLoad so the add function will be bound to that instead of the window, so add doesn't exist to the button

Comment: @George is right. Change it to "no wrap - botton of body" and it will work.

Comment: okay that's a weird default setting, I thought my javascript code was available in the HTML window .. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is specific to JSFiddle. You need to change the `LOAD TYPE` to `No wrap - bottom of <body>`.

When using onLoad, the function won't become global one, so you can't invoke it directy from HTML. If it is global - like when using no-wrap - it works.

[image: here]

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the best solution for call a function in current times is to use ES6. You can create for example something like that:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.class');

x.addEventListener('click', function() {

});

x.addEventListener('click', () => {

});
```