# Why doesn't <video> autoplay trigger "play" event?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, addeventlistener

Why doesn't play event get triggered when the video with autoplay first starts playing after loading the page?

```js
document.getElementById("vid").addEventListener('play', function, false);
```

```html
<video id="vid" src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay></video>
```

It should fire the play event I think, but doesn't.

Is this by design? and if so, why?

Manually pressing play works normally.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do something when video starts playing. In Firefox.

Comment: It works tho, so again what's the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/d1sgqnfL/

Comment: You get an alert when the page loads and the video starts playing after a reload? *in Firefox https://jsfiddle.net/usrnm/y3gm74wz/1/

Comment: Yes, but please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835963/beginner-level-button-not-calling-my-js-function/53836077#53836077) to understand what you need to do for it to work on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

For future users, this could be caused by a race condition between the time the video starts auto-playing and the event handler being added.

If the handler is added **after the video has already started playing**, the play event will not fire. This can happen when scripts are added at the bottom of a page and the video element above is set to autoplay.

See the snippet below:

```js
// add the handler after 500ms which assumes the video is already playing
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#vid').addEventListener('play', (e) => {
    console.info('playing');
  });;
}, 500);

// this will fire as expected
// document.querySelector('#vid').addEventListener('play', (e) => {
//  console.info('playing');
// });;
```

```html
<video height="100px" id="vid" src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay controls></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it depends on the browsers, you can get more info here to understand how Chrome works for example:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

What you can try for Chrome is to mute the video with the attribute `muted` and let the user unmute it:

```
<video id="vid" src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay muted></video>

<script>
document.getElementById("vid").addEventListener('play', function, false);
</script>
```

See it in action here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqLxZV?editors=1011

Comment: How would muting it help? I'm on Firefox by the way. One thing I noticed is, if I load the tab in the background, when I switch to it and the video auto starts, it fires the event, but if the tab has focus from the very start, it doesn't fire.

Comment: If you mute your video then Chrome will allow the video to autoplay, otherwise you can't let videos autoplay on Chrome with sound.

Comment: Ah. My problem is that "play" event doesn't get triggered when video autoplays. Not that video doesn't autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

It should work according to the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/semantics-embedded-content.html#media-elements-event-summary):

[image]

From tests on Safari (12.0.2) and Chrome (71.0.3578.98) on OSX (10.12.6) it does appear to work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple Video Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Video Test</h1>
  <video id="theVideo" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">
  </video>
</body>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("theVideo");
vid.onplay = function() {
    alert("Starting to play video");
};
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you just post an answer just to tell him that there's nothing wrong and everything is working? :P

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy - well, I tested that the functionality worked on two different browsers and provided, IMHO,  a clearer working example which can be reused. If this is what you are asking, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way by fixing the `addEventListener` parameters.

```js
document.getElementById("vid").addEventListener('play', function(){alert("test")});
```

```html
<video id="vid" src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay></video>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/usrnm/y3gm74wz/1/